# grep -wF "example1@domain1.org" filename.txt and special characters

Tags: unix, search, grep, special-characters

Inside filename.txt I've:

```
example1@domain1.org example1@domain1.org
example2@domain1.org example2@domain1.org
example3@domain1.org newexample3@domain1.org
example4@domain1.org oldexample4@domain1.org
example5@domain1.org otherexample5@domain1.org
```

I need search inside it the exact match, the result of:

```
grep -wF "example1@domain1.org" filename.txt
```

it's correct.

My problem is that grep show me correct result also if I do:

```
grep -wF "example1" filename.txt
```

maybe, is the @ (special characters) problem.

```
-w, --word-regexp
-F, --fixed-strings
```

Comment: It's tough to figure what you're trying to ask.

Comment: ok devnull, I changed my question :-)

Comment: So do you want lines that exactly match your pattern?

Comment: yep I only need exact line, later I check it with echo $?, thanks

Comment: As commented by @ooga just now, use the `-x` option.

Answer (score 1):

Word characters in grep consist of letters, digits, and underscores. So @ will end a word.
http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Matching-Control.html#Matching-Control

Comment: mhmh... so which tools do I need use to solve my problem? Thanks!

Comment: get rid of the `w` flag and use the `x` (exact line) flag.

Comment: ooga thank you, but also using -xF (or only -x) does not work :-/